# How to use data-desc for ionic fab button when we use react as development library in react?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-react

```
data-desc="Sales"
```

Above attribute is when we use angular as development framework in react. What if I want use react as development library, and want to give data description for the ionic icon inside ionic fab button? how to acheive this?